# How to reassign a reactive variable in Vue+TS?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
export default {
name: 'AuthCallback',
data() {
    return {
        accessToken: null,
    }
},
mounted() {
    const tokenParseRegex: RegExp = /access_token=(.*?)&/;
    const idParseRegex: RegExp = /user_id(.*?)/;
    const exAccessToken: RegExpMatchArray | null = useRoute().hash.match(tokenParseRegex);
    this.data().accessToken =  exAccessToken![1];
}
```

}

this.data().accessToken =  exAccessToken![1] - Whats wrong with this line?
Error is The type "string" cannot be assigned to the type "null". and in console this.data is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
this.accessToken = exAccessToken![1]
```

Instead of

```
this.data().accessToken = exAccessToken![1]
```

The error comes up because you are writing "data()" after "this", so it's being interpreted as a function.

While acessing data, you can simply use
`this.nameOfVar`

Comment: Yep, it works, but still have error: 
Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type '{ name: string; data(): { accessToken: ProxyConstructor; }; Mounted(): void; }'.

Comment: Try to assign the type any, to the accessToken variable. If the error vanishes, proceed to infer the correct type to accessToken. Right now, you are setting the type as null, by doing so, accessToken can only be null. if exAccessToken[1] is a string, try to set accessToken as following: `accessToken: null | string`

Comment: @Viassone `null` in data is JS expression, not a type, you can't use  `null | string` there

Comment: @Viassone check ss https://i.gyazo.com/144b0f445080e303c92b5eb72dc0d18f.png

Comment: and btw i still have that error:
https://i.gyazo.com/4055f2b633cac2ea938014a605e42b83.png

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try by expanding your `data` object by assigning a type to it.

```
data() : { accessToken: null | string }
{
    return {
        accessToken: null,
    }
}
```